# Graphopper options in leaflet

Tags: leaflet, graphhopper

I have a leaflet map, using graphopper as the router. I'm having problems with setting the options; for instance change the vehicle from default (car) to motorcycle.

```
routeControl = new L.Routing.Control({
    waypoints: setWaypoints,
    show: false,
    routeWhileDragging: true,
    router: L.Routing.graphHopper("api key"),
    vehicle: "motorcycle"
}).addTo(map);
```

Any help in the right direction is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the problem by using;

routeControl.getRouter().options.urlParameters.vehicle = 'motorcycle';
  routeControl.route();

after it was added to the map. Apparently motorcycle is not included in the free account but this approach works for the car, foot and bike.

I was wondering if there is a better solution for implementing this, because this way takes an extra step.

Comment: Thanks for solution, but it fires twice an consume 2 credits and not one

Answer (score 0):

my solution fires once:

```
var router = L.Routing.control({
 waypoints: [
    L.latLng(xx, xx),
    L.latLng(xx, xx)
  ],
  router: L.Routing.graphHopper("apiKey here"),
});
router.getRouter().options.urlParameters.vehicle = 'bike'; /* car, foot and bike. */
router.addTo(map);
```